# where to start with Add-in in Visual Studio when installed in Mac

Tags: vba, macos, visual-studio, excel, vsto

Dear VBA/VSTO programmers.

I started some months ago programming VBA in excel and now I want to jump into add-ins programmed in visual-studio.

I have three questions.
a) I installed visual studio in my mac, and following this instructions:
Creating the Project
To create a new Excel VSTO Add-in project in Visual Studio

1. Start Visual Studio. On the File menu, point to New, and then click
   Project. In the templates pane, expand Visual C# or Visual Basic,
   and then expand Office/SharePoint. Under the expanded
   Office/SharePoint node, select the Office Add-ins node. In the list
   of project templates, select Excel 2010 Add-in or Excel 2013 Add-in.
   In the Name box, type FirstExcelAddIn. Click OK.

but visual studio for mac does not give me the option of "project". how is that possible.

Do I have to go away from mac to program in viSUAL STUDIO ADD-INS FOR EXCEL?

Assuming I have a Mac Pro and I have a normal windows machine at work, but no excel in Mac Pro, can I do something of my programming in my mac pro at home for my excel at work? (I don't work as a programmer, just programming since a few months VBA).

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

VSTO add-ins can't be run on MAC. You need to develop COM based Office add-ins on Windows and have the desktop edition of MS Office installed if you want to be able to debug them.

You may consider creating [web add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins) instead. They can be loaded by Office for MAC too.